# FirebaseMessaging forground listener not getting DATA message from API

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Listener will pick up a "notification" message using the Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) but if i send in a "data" message it never gets to my listener. From my understanding in the docs I want "Data" because I want to use local notification to handle the display and not the default of popup of "Notification" through firebase. From what I have read this may be an issue with firebase?

I do understand I am using the legacy API. But just want to get the push message cycle set up.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
    if (message.notification != null) {
    }
  });
```

"Notification" message

```
{
 "to": "fHBcTCNttkyrt-...",
 "notification": {
     "title": "Test title",
     "body": "test",
     "content_available": true,
     "priority": "high"
}
```

}

Data Message

```
{
"to": "fHBcTCNttkyrt-....",
"data": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "contentAvailable": true,
    "priority": "high"
}
```